# How do I access sub-control's HtmlControl.Style in user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, user-controls

I have a user control that contains the following text (among other things) in the .ascx file:

```
<div id="divLine" runat="server">
    <-- Stuff -->
</div>
```

In the C# code, I have this property:

```
[Browsable(false)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public CssStyleCollection LeftStyle
{
    get { return divLeft.Style; }
}
```

This is pretty much copied from `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlControl.cs`.  However, when trying to use my custom control in .aspx pages, I can't seem to access `<uwc:UserControl LeftStyle="stuff">` like I could access it directly in `<div style="stuff">`.  Is there any way to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer, so I took a different approach.  `divLine` only contained an asp.net `Label`, which I exposed as a public property of the control.  Apparently you can do things like `<asp:Label runat="server" style="stuff"/>`.  Intellisense will not indicate that `style` is a valid attribute, but it can still be used.  Just like other asp.net controls, attributes the IDE doesn't recognize will still be written to HTML.  Heck, once you get `style="` written, you'll even get the typical drop-down guide for it.